# conditional if on import for objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to use conditional if on import for objective c, didn't see any API for this and wanted to know if this is possible.
(this is for adding an import only for a specific IOS)
so far I saw this check but it's only for the code, not at the import stage
Thanks

```
if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
    // Use iOS 11 APIs.
} else {
    // Alternative code for earlier versions of iOS.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the foundation framework version numbers, like so.

```
#ifdef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_0
#import "this.h"
#else
#import "that.h"
#endif
```

or even

```
#if NSFoundationVersionNumber > 10
#import "this.h"
#else
#import "that.h"
#endif
```

This is a bit different to the `@available` that you mention, which checks at runtime. This will check on compile time and depend on your target iOS and it seems it is no longer kept up to date, but worth a try if your requirement is compile time.

Comment: thanks, wasn't aware of this, but what is this is a framework that doesn't exist in an old OS, how do I compile it in an old xcode as well as a new one?

Comment: Suppose ```this``` only compiles in new Xcode and ```that``` in old, this should work. You probably need some additional configuration, ie only include ```this.m``` in new and only include ```that.m``` in old Xcode. The problem is that your whole project then is fragmented into one for old and one for new Xcode, but at least you should be able to compile it.

Comment: Same for a framework, if framework ```this``` only works in new and ```that``` in old Xcode you need to fragment the project and include only the relevant framework in the relevant Xcode, but at least this source file will be the same across both.

Comment: Finally, if you are going to compile this with two different Xcodes it actually gives you more freedom to define your own things. So in one of the projects you can define a variable and test for that. Then you do not need to use e.g. the framework as here.

Comment: thanks, but not sure what you mean by fragment the code
If there a framework <Bla/Bla.h>
how do I make sure the import will be only for a new IOS/new xcode?
the #if NSBlaVersionNumber or something like this for the new framework will not help here since the old xcode will not recognize it

Comment: If you use two Xcodes to compile you can #define individually for each one and then use that. So in Xcode 7 you can #define XC7 eg and same for say Xcode 11. Then you can put anything, also #include's, in #ifdef XC7 ... #endif and #ifdef XC11 ... #endif. Here the dots ... can be anything you require for only that Xcode. So you can use the same source code but these conditional compiles can be used to treat things differently based on which Xcode compiles it. This can include frameworks also. Does this clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the `#import` is a compiler pre-processor directive - it has an effect when your code is compiled.  The version of iOS is only known at run time; when your code *executes*.

The toolchain knows the minimum level of iOS that your app supports because you tell it through the project settings, but it can't recompile your code based on the iOS version encountered when the code is run.

At run time you can use alternate code paths using the `#available` test you referred to in your question.

Comment: thanks, ,my question is for cases when I have a new framework and I want my code to run on an older xcode. with older IOS, is that possible. XCode has different flags for preprocessing like DEBUG for example and I'm wondering if there is something like this for IOS version/Xcode version or something else that gives me this functionality

Comment: Generally you would have people specifically use an older version of your framework in that case

Comment: what if there's no older framework version and simply it's the first time the framework is added for the IOS version/Xcode, is there a way to check it?

Comment: Anyone releasing an app today will be using Xcode 11, since Apple won't accept a build created with an earlier version nor can you submit using Xcode 12 yet (it is still beta), so if you are releasing today you shouldn't have an issue with Xcode. You can handle older iOS at runtime via `#available`. Since you have tagged objective C you should have even fewer issues than with Swift since you don't have to worry about swift version changes between Xcode versions

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason not to import headers. Importing headers and using functionality contained inside them is a different thing.

You can import headers if they are accessible during compilation. You only have to check for iOS version before using classes and functions inside them.

Checking platform before importing is common only if you want your code to be compiled on different platforms, e.g. iOS and MacOS, which have completely different headers.

Comment: the reason is that if I want to support a new OS that has a new framework or new constants and I want it to compile using an old xcode and old OS prior to the new one, I would like to know if this is possible, the API @available is for runtime and trying to surround new code around it with unrecognized constants fails compilation

Comment: @user2679041 Thats not how compilation works. You are asking for impossible things.

Comment: I thought it was an issue, wanted to know if there's a way around it, thanks

Comment: @user2679041 Of course you can compile on an older Xcode (there is `#available` directive) but then you wouldn't be able to access the new constant in code.